# Why does my fetch function result in a 'Network request failed' in Expo?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I want to store videos along with their thumbnails (expo-video-thumbnails) using Expo with a Firebase back-end. I can pass videos  through my fetch function but whenever I try doing the same with the thumbnails I catch a 'Network request failed' error.

I've been trying to fix this for a while now without success. Here is my code - I'd gladly appreciate some help with this!

```
    export const saveMediaToStorage = (media, path) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const fileRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(path)

       fetch(media)
           .then(response => response.blob())
           .then(blob => fileRef.put(blob))
           .then(task => task.ref.getDownloadURL())
           .then(downloadUrl => resolve(downloadUrl))
           // .catch(() => reject())
           .catch((e) => {console.error(e)})
})
```

Edit: I am using an Android Emulator

Comment: The problem seems to stem from the media I am fetching. expo-video-thumbail is giving me an undefined thumbnail which I do not understand why...

Answer (score 1):

Does your link use https? or http? you might want to use https?

Comment: Wanted to comment instead but didn't have enough reputation lol

Comment: No problem! I have seen this answer on an older stack overflow post - however, I am a noob when it comes to backend. Could you please elaborate where 'my link' would be? I don't seem to have any link in my code using https or http.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).